# Словообразовательная цепочка слова "засахарилось"

Tags: словообразование

Можете помочь составить словообразовательную цепочку слова "засахарилось"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сахар -> сахар-и(ть) -> за-сахарить -> засахарить-ся.

Answer (score 1):

**Сахар — за/сахар/и/ть/ся.**

Глагол ***засахариться*** мотивирован существительным ***сахар***, способ образования префиксально-суффиксально-постфиксальный.

**ЗАСАХАРИТЬСЯ**,  Загустеть, выделив **сахар** (о варенье, мёде). Варенье засахарилось.

Это значение не относится к значению глаголов *сахарить и засахарить*.

**ЗАСАХАРИТЬ**, св. что. Приготовить варкой в сахарном сиропе; покрыть, насытить сахаром. З. фрукты. З. клюкву.

**САХАРИТЬ**, что. Разг. Посыпать сахаром, класть сахар во что-л. С. тесто.

[https://vnutrislova.net/разбор/по-составу/засахариться](https://vnutrislova.net/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80/%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%83/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F)